# Installing CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'd like to install CakePHP on my xampp server by each project.
root/project1
root/project2

and I'd like to access this by localhost/project1, localhost/project2.
Project1 would be my test site, the other one going to be publishing.
Here is an error message "project1Controller could not be found"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ServerAlias localhost/project1
   ServerAdmin admin@yahoo.com
   DocumentRoot "C:/root/cakephp/project1/app/webroot"
   <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride FileInfo
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ServerAlias localhost/project2
   ServerAdmin admin@yahoo.com
   DocumentRoot "C:/root/cakephp/project2/app/webroot"
   <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride FileInfo
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please advise me.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DocumentRoot should not be the webroot folder, it needs to be the very root of the whole Cake project. Try changing it to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost/project1
  ServerAdmin admin@yahoo.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/root/cakephp/project1"
  <Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride FileInfo
     Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Cake's `.htaccess` and front controller will take care of routing for you. You don't need to try to access the webroot directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem configuring Apache until I gave up and change to Hiawatha, much more easy to configure and according some benchmark is faster than Apache.

Here is my receipt on **how to set up a server with Hiawatha-PHP-MariaDB**:

1. Install MariaDB

   ```
   sudo yum -y install mariadb mariadb-server
   sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
   sudo systemctl enable mariadb.service
   ```
2. Configure mysql:

   ```
   sudo mysql_secure_installation
   ```
3. Install Hiawatha:

   ```
   sudo yum install yum-utils
   sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo http://repo.hiawatha.be 
   sudo rpm --import http://repo.hiawatha.be/pubkey 
   sudo yum install hiawatha
   sudo systemctl enable hiawatha.service
   ```
4. Install php5-fpm:

   ```
   sudo yum -y install php-fpm php-mysql php-cli
   sudo nano /etc/php.ini
   ```
5. Set this paramenter: `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0`
6. Remove comments:

   ```
   #pm.min_spare_servers = 5 
   #pm.max_spare_servers = 35
   ```
7. Restart php-fpm:

   ```
   systemctl restart php-fpm.service
   ```

And here is the `/etc/hiawatha/hiawatha.conf` file:

```
ServerId = www-data
ConnectionsTotal = 1000
ConnectionsPerIP = 25
SystemLogfile = /var/log/hiawatha/system.log
GarbageLogfile = /var/log/hiawatha/garbage.log
Binding {
        Port = 80
}
Binding {
        Port = 443
        SSLcertFile = /etc/hiawatha/serverkey.pem
}

CGIhandler = /usr/bin/php5-cgi:php,php5

FastCGIserver {
        FastCGIid = PHP5
        ConnectTo = 127.0.0.1:9000
        Extension = php
}

UrlToolkit {
   ToolkitID = cakephp
   RequestURI exists Return
   Match .* Rewrite /index.php
}

Hostname = serverIpAddress
WebsiteRoot = /var/www
StartFile = index.html
AccessLogfile = /var/log/hiawatha/access.log
ErrorLogfile = /var/log/hiawatha/error.log
UseFastCGI = PHP5

VirtualHost {
        Hostname = www.example.com
        WebsiteRoot = /var/www/example.com
        StartFile = index.php
        AccessLogfile = /var/www/example.com/access.log
        ErrorLogfile =  /var/www/example/error.log
        RequireSSL = yes
        TimeForCGI = 5
        UseFastCGI = PHP5
        UseToolkit = cakephp
}
VirtualHost {
        Hostname = host2.example.com
        WebsiteRoot = /var/www/anotherexample
        StartFile = index.php
        AccessLogfile = /var/www/anotherexample/logs/access.log
        ErrorLogfile =  /var/www/anotherexample/logs/error.log
        RequireSSL = yes
        TimeForCGI = 5
        UseFastCGI = PHP5
        UseToolkit = cakephp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For new version(Cakephp 3.x) you can only use

open command prompt and go to your project directory. After this run this command

`bin\cake server`

when your command execute then your default server would be `localhost:8765`